# Why is the subquery not working in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to run this query in Snowflake, but I keep getting an error.

```
select x.*, (select z.status from TBLA z where z.number_id=x.number_id and z.country=x.country and z.datetime=x.datetime) status
from
(
    select a.number_id, a.country, max(datetime) as datetime
    from TBLA a
    group by a.number_id, a.country
) x
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason for using a subquery for the status rather than just joining TBLA to the  x table?

Answer (score 0):

To get the status for the latest datetime per number_id/country windowed function could be used:

```
SELECT a.*, 
  (ARRAY_AGG(a.status) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY a.datetime DESC) 
                       OVER(PARTITION BY a.number_id, a.country))[0] AS latest_status
FROM TBLA a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get the latest status by number_id and country. A simple query to do that in Snowflake using window function row_number() is

```
select * from TBLA
qualify row_number() over (partition by number_id, country order by datetime desc) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Only scalar subqueries are allowed in the SELECT. Your subquery is not inherently scalar.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html